# How do you separate tags you're interested in and tags you have expertise in?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tag-watching

I have one problem which is bothering me in my daily interaction with SO. My list of favourite tags consists mainly of two more or less mutually exclusive groups of tags.

- **Know how topics** I want highlighted and pointed out to me because I want to write answers, comments, edits, etc.
- **Want to learn topics** I just want to follow and read up on for learning purposes.

I could solve this problem easily, if it were possible to group tags and assign each group a different highlight colour as well as subscribe to a separate feed.

How do you handle this and what do you think of this potential solution?

Comment: Does really nobody else have this problem? Why not?

Answer (score 1):

For me personally, the latter category simply isn't in my "interesting" tags because it doesn't make sense for me to follow questions in tags I don't know anything about. If I want to learn something, I will actively look around or search in the tag's questions.

But if you do things differently, I can see how this is a real problem... It *should* be possible to build a userscript for this half-way easily. Maybe someone wants to give it a shot?

Comment: [Meme reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19495/168428)!